# Excel function to create due dates that land on a business day

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm stuck creating a formula that will calculate days before the end of the month then adjust to make sure it is a business day.  For example: 30 days before 6/30/2015 is 5/31/2015 which is a Sunday.  I need that to adjust to the Friday before.

I'm working on finding the due dates of a number of documents that are due a certain number of days before another date.  For example: documents are due 30 days before the last day of the month.  However, the number of days varies and the due date needs to fall on a business day (Monday-Friday).  Sometimes it's 30 days, sometimes it's 60 days, sometimes it's 30 calendar days + 5 business days, etc.

I've been able to calculate 30 days + 5 business days with the following formula:

`=workday(start_date-30,-5)`

Any ideas how to adjust this so that I can just have the due date be 30 calendar days before a certain date but also always be a business day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to write a macro function or maybe some nested IF statements in your cell's formula.

Take a look at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/481558-round-date-nearest-workday.html

That solution moves forward to the nearest workday, but the principle is sound: just subtract instead of add.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to edit the formula to do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `WORKDAY` you can use a formula like this:

```
=WORKDAY(A1+B1+1,-1)
```

where `A1` is your start date and `B1` the number of days to add.